# Seekbar's thumb on click listner

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I would like to register a clickable event on the seekbar's thumb in order to open activity when the user has cliked it. Is it possible? I have found similar question here 
[Seekbar's thumb on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684463/seekbars-thumb-on-click) but found no answer.
I don't want to move seek bar but want to open activity when user clicks only on the thump of seekbar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Seekbar's thumb on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684463/seekbars-thumb-on-click)

Comment: Yes. Its duplicate question. I also mention that but there is no correct answer. See the last comment "I want to be able to click only in the thumb. That listener is triggered clicking in every part of the seek bar". I am also in  the same position. Please help me. I have searched a lot but not able to find the answer

Answer (score 0):

This will fire when the user clicks on the thumb. See the beginning of onProgressChanged() Hope this helps. :)

If you have any questions about how it works feel free to comment.

```
mSeekBarSpeed.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    int progress = mSeekBarSpeed.getProgress();

    boolean started = false; //use this variable to see whether the user clicked the right place


    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
        if(!started){ //check to see if user clicks the right place
            //if the user clicks within a specific threshold
            float threshold = (float)seekBar.getMax() / seekBar.getWidth() * seekBar.getThumb().getIntrinsicWidth() / 2;
            if(Math.abs(progressValue - progress) < threshold){
                 if(fromUser){ //checks if user actually clicked it
                     started = true;

                     //IF YOU WANT TO DO SOMETHING RIGHT WHERE THE USER CLICKS IT HERE IS THE PLACE
                 }

            }else{
                seekBar.setProgress(progress); //set to original progress
                onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar); //not really necessary, keep or delete based on your needs
                return; //get out of method
            }
        }

        if(started) {

            progress = progressValue; //update progress variable
            System.out.println("onProgressChanged:" + progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());

            //DO WHAT YOU NEED TO DO WHEN PROGRESS IS CHANGING

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        System.out.println("onStartTracking:" + progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        System.out.println("onStopTracking:" + progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());
        //DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO WHEN PROGRESS IS DONE CHANGING

        started = false; //remember to set variable to false
    }

});
```