# Detect click events on Android SeekBar's Thumb

Tags: android, android-custom-view, seekbar

Is there a better way to detect click events on the Android Seekbar's thumb; other than to overlap the thumb's position with a transparent view and detect clicks on it?

Comment: Read Documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html

Comment: you mean http://stackoverflow.com/q/11684463/3790150

Comment: its incorrect - it detects click event on the whole seekbar :)

Comment: see `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener`